# Multiple dex error

Tags: android

If I Click the **Graphical Layout** I am getting this below Exception:

```
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
```

Then in **Java Build path** ->**order and export**:

[image]

In the above screenshot if I `check` the `android.support.v4.jar` I am getting the below Multiple Dex error in console:

```
[2014-11-04 18:35:30 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2014-11-04 18:35:30 - qmr-android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Comment: Why did you delete almost all of your question? Now it doesn't make much sense...and the below answer is completely meaningless without the original question.

Comment: Please ask a new question for each problem you encounter. Editing your question with entirely new information means that this will not be useful to anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- These Error occurred because of the android-support-v4.jar.This jar
  wasn't updated in my project. It size is nearly 325 kb.So that I
  realize to check the jar from other sample application. In that
  sample application the jar size would be 530 kb.Then I find it,qmr
  project jar was an error.It is not an updated jar. So I removed the
  jar placed in qmr and added the sample project jar.Then it solved my
  problem.
- The error would be occur if I place a jar in this
  directory`(E:\Android
  Eclipse\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v4)`. This Directory is
  applicable to add a jar. But not in my project.
- Because other jars like gson.jar,libgoogleanalytics.jar have a
  directory in `E:\workspace\Workspace1\sample-android\libs.`So in my project,add a jar in same directory solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to add a navigation drawer, declare your user interface with a DrawerLayout object as the root view of your layout. Inside the DrawerLayout, add one view that contains the main content for the screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.But you have created multiple views in your layout (Try to include that all views except the FrameLayout into a single parent view). see [creating a navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for more info.

Also, make sure you have added the Android v4 support library to your project, and that you have updated ADT and Eclipse to the latest and follow these simple steps

Right click your project, go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Go to the Order and export tab

Check the libraries. And hit Ok

Then go to Project in the main menu, and Clean your project, to rebuild it and try and run it again.